# eclipse shortcuts ctrl+z and ctrl+y select all

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I have to work on Eclipse but its shortcuts are broken, because when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> it selects all, like a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (and not every time, but approximately 1 time out of 3).

I tried to `Restore default` shortcuts in `Window > Preference > General > Keys` but nothing changed. In the config window it seems good: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is marked as `undo`, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> is marked as `redo` and only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is marked as `select all` command.

Any suggestions?

---

I eventually figured out that this happens when I do some changes and then save it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. The save seems to add something in the action history and, for that reason, when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, it selects all.

Comment: Does eclipse reformat the code and then when you hit the keys select the lines formatted?

Comment: what do you mean by "reformat the code" ?

Comment: In the preferences search for "Save Actions" in Java. There you will find certain checkboxes. One says "Format source code". This will cause reformatting the code everytime you hit the save button. Formatting happens according to your custom formatter.

Comment: Ok I found it, the "perform selected actions on save" checkbox is unchecked

Comment: It's just a guess but try observing it.

Comment: It is unchecked in java, js and project specific setting, do you want me to test with the "format source code" option enabled ?

Comment: It feels like it is an "after-build" action

Comment: For anyone else still dealing with this (I was having this problem even with the 2024 version), it stopped when I moved my project from my Google Drive folder back to a local folder. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Check keyboard Layout. Sometimes due to keyboard layout key perform different functionalities.It happens with me sometime. May be it will work for you.

Comment: I use VSCode too for another project, and it doesn't select all, is there another configuration from Eclipse for keyboard layout ?